# Unable to draw google Line Chart with Multiple columns with different data types

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, google-visualization

I am facing issues while implementing multi-line google chart. While plotting the line chart I am getting "All the series on given axis must be of the same data type".

Below is my Google line chart code snippet and I am fetching the values of frmyear, toyear and makes from database.(It is dynamic drop-down list).

```
function drawChart(frmyear, toyear, makes) 
{
        alert('hiii');
        console.log(makes);
        $_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
        var jsondata = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'salesone',
            data: {frmyear: frmyear, toyear: toyear, makes: makes, _token: $_token },

            }).success(function(data) {
            }).done(function(data){

        jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(jsondata);
        drawgraph(jsondata);
     })
       .fail(function(data) {
       alert( "error" );
    });

  }


  function drawgraph(jsondata)
  {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata);

      var options = {
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, {width: 200, height: 300});
  chart.draw(data, options);

  }
```

If user select two brands e.g. Mahindra & Hyundai for duration of Jan 2011 to June 2011 then my JSON data looks like below:

```
{"cols":[{"label":"Datetime","type":"date"},{"label":"Make","type":"string"},{"label":"Sales","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 0, 31)"},{"v":"Hyundai"},{"v":28989}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 1, 28)"},{"v":"Hyundai"},{"v":31405}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 2, 31)"},{"v":"Hyundai"},{"v":30529}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 3, 30)"},{"v":"Hyundai"},{"v":30522}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 4, 31)"},{"v":"Hyundai"},{"v":30076}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 5, 30)"},{"v":"Hyundai"},{"v":29461}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 0, 31)"},{"v":"Mahindra"},{"v":16620}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 1, 28)"},{"v":"Mahindra"},{"v":14523}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 2, 31)"},{"v":"Mahindra"},{"v":16044}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 3, 30)"},{"v":"Mahindra"},{"v":14709}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 4, 31)"},{"v":"Mahindra"},{"v":15892}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 5, 30)"},{"v":"Mahindra"},{"v":15286}]}]}
```

Here I have three columns Datetime, Make & Sales and all are of different data types hence I am unable to plot Line chart for Hyundai & Mahindra.

I want the data in below format:

```
Date                Hyndai          Mahindra
Date(2011, 1, 28)   31405           16620
Date(2011, 2, 31)   30529           14523 
Date(2011, 3, 30)   30522           16044
```

In this case either I have to create data view or I need to modify the JSON. But in both approaches I will not be aware of how many brands selected by user.

My application is in Laravel 5.1 & MySQL as Database. what is the possible solution available to plot the line graph using google charts in this scenario?